# Javascript shortcut for setting within day time components of a javascript date to 0?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Wondering if there is a "Shorter" way to do this in order to create a date that has the hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds all set to 0:

```
const d = new Date();
d.setHours(0);
d.setMinutes(0);
d.setSeconds(0);
d.setMilliseconds(0);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can just do `new Date(new Date().toDateString())`

```js
const d = new Date(new Date().toDateString())
console.log(d)
```

```js
const d = new Date();
d.setHours(0);
d.setMinutes(0);
d.setSeconds(0);
d.setMilliseconds(0);
console.log(d);
```

Comment: Not so cool: unnecessary conversion to string and parsing. Look in dupe reference: `new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))`